# What happens when BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP is written as BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Class, GrandParentClass)?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I came across a piece of code where BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP for a class has it's Grandparent Class as the second parameter. I know that when it's the parent class, if the child class doesn't handle the message, it checks whether the parent class does. I couldn't find documentation for the case of the Grandparent class. Is the behavior similar? Would it skip checking the parent class's message map and check in the grandparent class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` is a macro, so you can look at the expanded code and see what it does. The exact definition may vary with the version, but it is more or lees:

```
#define BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(theClass, baseClass) \
    const AFX_MSGMAP* PASCAL theClass::_GetBaseMessageMap() \
        { return &baseClass::messageMap; } \
    const AFX_MSGMAP* theClass::GetMessageMap() const \
        { return &theClass::messageMap; } \
    AFX_COMDAT AFX_DATADEF const AFX_MSGMAP theClass::messageMap = \
    { &theClass::_GetBaseMessageMap, &theClass::_messageEntries[0] }; \
    AFX_COMDAT const AFX_MSGMAP_ENTRY theClass::_messageEntries[] = \
    { \
```

Not too easy to read... but the `baseClass` is only used in the non-virtual function `_GetBaseMessageMap` that returns the base map. This is used in return to build the first piece of the real `theClass::messageMap`, that is a list of pointers to pieces of the full message map (the other piece being the mapping of this class).

TL;DR; Yes, for any message not processed in this class, it will skip the map of the parent class and go directly to that of the grandparent class.